# Making spans inside of figures displayed in one line

Tags: html, css, inline, figure

I want the following 3 figures to get displayed all in one line:

```css
.hero.sec{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<center>
   <div class="about" id="abt">
  <div class="abtcontent">
     <be>
     <h1 style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 5px solid black; border-radius: 5px; width: 7%; margin-left: 0;"><b>About</b></h1>
     <p style="color:black">Lorem Ipasum</p>
     <center>
        <div class="hero.sec">
           <h2>
              <figure>
                 <span class="num" data-val="650">000</span>
           </h2>
           <figcaption>Lines of Code</figcaption></figure>
           <h2>
              <figure>
                 <span class="num" data-val="50">000</span>
           </h2>
           <figcaption>Scam Servers detected</figcaption></figure>
           <figure>
              <h2><span class="num" data-val="10"></span></h2>
              <figcaption>Legit Servers listed</figcaption>
           </figure>
        </div>
     </center>
  </div>
   </div>
</center>
```

However, I still get a new line for every single figure. Can someone help me?

Comment: Firstly you need to rename your class name, `.hero.sec` in a CSS file means target the element which has class both hero and sec (e.g `class="hero sec"`). So it would be better to rename it as `hero-sec` for example.

Comment: Just a side note: the center tag is now deprecated. Center elements using standard CSS techniques instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should organize your tags first, Also Multi classes in HTML must be separated by space not '.', The following code will display figures in the same line as you requested:

```
<center>
   <div class="about" id="abt">
      <div class="abtcontent">
         <br>
         <h1 style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 5px solid black; border-radius: 5px; width: 7%; margin-left: 0;"><b>About</b></h1>
         <p style="color:black">Lorem Ipasum</p>
         <div class="hero sec">
            <figure>
               <h2>
                  <span class="num" data-val="650">000</span>
               </h2>
               <figcaption>Lines of Code</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
               <h2>
                  <span class="num" data-val="50">000</span>
               </h2>
               <figcaption>Scam Servers detected</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
               <h2><span class="num" data-val="10"></span></h2>
               <figcaption>Legit Servers listed</figcaption>
            </figure>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</center>
```

Css :

```
figure {
             display: inline-block;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you messed up your `<figure>` start tag, you have put it after `h2` insted in front of, and for displaying inline use this under:

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<center><div class="about" id="abt">
    <div class="abtcontent">
      <br><h1 style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 5px solid black; border-radius: 5px; width: 7%; margin-left: 0;"><b>About</b></h1>
      <p style="color:black">Lorem Ipasum</p>
      <center><div class="hero.sec">
        <figure><h2><span class="num" data-val="650">000</span></h2><figcaption>Lines of Code</figcaption></figure>
       <figure><h2><span class="num" data-val="50">000</span></h2><figcaption>Scam Servers detected</figcaption></figure>
        <figure><h2><span class="num" data-val="10"></span></h2><figcaption>Legit Servers listed</figcaption></figure>
      </div></center>
    </div>
  </div></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is wrong for css. Don't use .(dot) in classname. Default _(underscore) is using.